# How to convert Linq expression with multiple joins into method syntax OR retrieve select index?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have an existing (working!) linq expression:

```
from ca in db.CustomAnswer
join ss in db.SurveySubmission on ca.SubmissionId equals ss.Id
join cq in db.CustomQuestion on ca.QuestionId equals cq.Id
where (ss.SurveyId == request.SurveyId)
orderby ss.Submitted, cq.SortOrder
select new
{
    SubmissionId = ss.Id,
    Answer = ca.Answer
}
```

I want to add the index of the select into the new object, e.g.

```
from ca in db.CustomAnswer
join ss in db.SurveySubmission on ca.SubmissionId equals ss.Id
join cq in db.CustomQuestion on ca.QuestionId equals cq.Id
where (ss.SurveyId == request.SurveyId)
orderby ss.Submitted, cq.SortOrder
select new
{
    SubmissionId = ss.Id,
    **Code = selectIndex,**
    Answer = ca.Answer
}
```

To do this, I believe I need to first convert my query to method syntax so I can use the `Select((q, index) => ...)` form.  To my simple mind, I think it should be:

```
  db.SurveySubmission
    .Where(ss => ss.SurveyId == request.SurveyId)
    .OrderBy(ss => ss.Submitted)
    .Join(db.CustomAnswer, ss => ss.Id, ca => ca.SubmissionId, (ss, ca) => new { ss, ca })
    .Join(db.CustomQuestion, o => o.ca.QuestionId, cq => cq.Id, (o, cq) => new { o.ss, o.ca, cq })
    .OrderBy(q => q.cq.SortOrder)
    .Select((q, idx) => new {
                                SubmissionId = q.ss.Id,
                                Answer = q.ca.Answer,
                                Code = idx
                            });
```

However, when the expression is evaluated I get an error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousTypef`3[System.Guid,System.String,System.Int32]]
>    Select[<>f_*AnonymousTypee`3,<>f__AnonymousTypef`3]
>   (System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousTypee`3[My.Data.Namespace.SurveySubmission,
>   My.Data.Namespace.CustomAnswer,My.Data.Namespace.CustomQuestion]], 
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[<>f*_AnonymousTypee`3[My.Data.Namespace.SurveySubmission,
>   My.Data.Namespace.CustomAnswer,My.Data.Namespace.CustomQuestion],System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousTypef`3[System.Guid,
>   System.String,System.Int32]]])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I'm hoping this is glaringly obvious to someone?  I've stared at it for several hours and the only conclusion I can make is that I'm not clever enough ... can anyone help please??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF can't translate that into SQL, because in SQL sets are unordered; the idea of an index just doesn't make any sense to it.

Instead do everything *but* getting the index using an EF query, and then tack on the indexes in a linq to objects query:

```
var query = //your original query goes here

var finalQuery = query.AsEnumerable()
    .Select((answer, index) => new
        {
            answer.SubmissionId,
            answer.Answer,
            Code = index,
        });
```

Comment: Ahah thankyousomuch - that makes sense (more so than the error!)!  The `AsEnumerable()` is critical here - without it I get the same error.  Is this deferred execution - because calling `AsEnumerable()` evaluates the expression?  Why?!?

Comment: @AndyC `AsEnumerable` ensures that the variable is typed as an `IEnumerable`, rather than an `IQueryable`, and so the methods called are the `IEnumerable` overloads, which, while they look the same, do entirely different things.

Comment: Man alive it's a jungle out there. Thanks @Servy for your help.